# Javascript NodeJS ES6 combination/permutations algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, permutation, ecmascript-6

Little challenge.

---

Goal (nodeJS, loop is an * interator function using "yield" strategy)

```
var str;
var minChars = 1;
var maxChars = 10;
for (str of loop('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',minChars,maxChars)) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

---

Constraints:

- Only generate string combinations length between minChars and maxChars
- Must not consumme all memory (Array in store not allowed)
- Must use ES6 iterators, so step by step is possible
- Recursion is allowed
- Can provide billions of combination

---

Sample output (order is important):

```
a
b
c
[...]
z
aa
ab
ac
[...]
aaa
aab
aac
[...]
aba
abb
abc
[...]
bza
bzb
bzc
[...]
zzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: Generate time is not important

Comment: i'm looking for a code solution, yes.

I didn't succeed on my side :( my brain is not wired for ...

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a place to do the coding for you if you include the code of what you have tried so far in the question then you'll have a better chance of getting help

Comment: @user1815190: At least show us your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Trivial solution:

```
function* loop(alphabet, min, max) {
    if (min > max) throw new RangeError("max needs to be greater than min");
    if (min <= 0)
        yield "";
    if (max > 0)
        for (const rest of loop(alphabet, min-1, max-1))
            for (const a of alphabet)
                yield rest+a;
}
```

([Babel demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=function*%20loop%28alphabet%2C%20min%2C%20max%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28min%20%3E%20max%29%20throw%20new%20RangeError%28%22max%20needs%20to%20be%20greater%20than%20min%22%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28min%20%3C%3D%200%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28max%20%3E%200%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28const%20rest%20of%20loop%28alphabet%2C%20min-1%2C%20max-1%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28const%20a%20of%20alphabet%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20rest%2Ba%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afor%20%28let%20x%20of%20loop%28%22ab%22%2C%201%2C%203%29%29%20console.log%28x%29%3B))

Comment: Could you possibly explain what `if (min <= 0) yield "";` is doing? I'm not super familiar with generators but it never seems to output an empty string, and taking that bit out causes it not to work. So what's the deal?

Comment: @idbehold: It's the base case of the recursion. `loop(…, 0, 0)` does have the empty string as the only combination, and `loop(…, 0, …)` starts with it. Admittedly, it might be cleaner (and more intuitive) to only allow non-negative values for `min` and `max`.